# C# equivalent to array_keys in PHP

Tags: c#, php

I would like to know if there is some method simular to the array_keys() function in PHP.

The method returns the keys of the array.

Here is the PHP code I would like to convert:

```
    public function example($ar = array()) {
        $keys = array_keys($ar);
}
```

Here is what I tried to do:

```
        public void Insert(string Table, string[] Fields)
    {
        object Keys = Fields.;
        string Values = "";
        int Number = 0;

        foreach(string Field in Fields) {
            String.Concat(Values, "?");
            if (Number < Fields.Length)
            {
                String.Concat(Values, ", ");
            }
            Number++;
        }
        string Command = "INSERT INTO " + Table + " (`" + String.Join("`, `", Keys) + " VALUES (" + Values + ")";
    }
```

Comment: Assuming you're working with a dictionary, `dict.Keys`?

Comment: How would I go about doing so, I am a beginner in C#.

Comment: You should explain what the function *does* rather than just posting the code.  That way people unfamiliar with PHP (but familiar with C#) can help more readily.

Comment: Have you written any code for this C# program at all? You should have something to work with, otherwise just converting a single method this way is kind of pointless since it doesn't belong to a complete program in either language. At the very least you should already know what kind of data you're working with. I'm just assuming you're working with a dictionary.

Comment: ___Please___ do not use string concatenation to build query values into your SQL.

Comment: Additionally, use one of the many built-in or 3rd party libraries for moving data via SQL. You shouldn't ever have to write SQL statements for CRUD operations in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the [Dictionary Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The following method takes in a `Dictionary` object and returns an array of the keys in the dictionary, which is according to what I understand from that PHP method.

```
public string[] GetDictionaryKeys(Dictionary<string, object> dict) {
    return dict.Keys.ToArray()
}
```

Comment: Good start, but I'd skip making a function that creates an array based on the keys. Just use the `Keys` property directly.

Comment: I was trying to emulate what his php code returns. But whatever works for him.

Comment: I subscribe to the controversial view that we should not simply provide a direct answer to the OP's question, but rather provide a right answer to the actual problem. If the OP asks "how can I simulate mouse clicks?" and the goal is to use that to open up the control panel and change settings, the right answer should not be to explain how to send mouseclick messages, but rather to explain how to change system settings programmatically.